# Как упаковать два числа с битовым смещением?

Tags: c#

Есть два числа (A - byte, B - ushort), нужно упаковать в int32 или short таким образом: в первые 3 бита записать A (число по определению будет не более 3 бита, даже если byte из 8 битов). А затем с 4 бита записать значение B. До конца не разобрался с операторами << и >>, как это сделать? И как это потом распаковать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(A & 7) | (B << 3)
```

или, что то же самое:

```
(A & 0b111) | (B << 3)
```

Здесь подразумевается, что "**первые** 3 бита"  - младшие, и "с **4** бита" использует нумерацию с единицы

Распаковка

```
A = C & 0b111
B = C >> 3                для unsigned С
B = (C >> 3) & 0x1FFF     для signed С (если почему-то требуется хранить в нём)
0x1FFF =  0b00011...11
```

Comment: `A & 0b111` наверное нагляднее использовать

Comment: @teran Да, будет полезно

Comment: @teran обычно HEX использут, я бы сказал даже в 90% случаев. Откройте исходники того же ffmpeg там много упаковок и распаковок.

Comment: @nick_n_a я рад конечно, что вам удобно двигать битовые маски в хексе, но подавляющему числу людей когда речь идет о битовых сдвигах удобнее использовать двоичное представление.

Comment: @teran очень спорное утверждение. Для меня битовая маска в HEX гораздо удобнее чем BIN, и думаю не только для меня. Откуда вам извесно о подавляющем большинстве? Вы проводили исследования на эту тему?

Comment: @nick_n_a то есть, допустим, надо проверить установку 7го и 3го бита, и вам удобнее писать `x & 48` и вы сразу сходу так все видите, понимаете, и это чертовски удобно? Пардоньте, конечно, но в моем представлении, человек встретивший такое в коде, сначала пойдет переводить это в бинарную форму, и только потом поймет о чем речь.  Одно дело задание констант и их использвоание, другое - непосредственное использование. Но эта наша дискуссия субъективна и основана на мнениях, так что не вижу смысла продолжать обсуждение. Удобен вам прямой хекс - пользуйтесь на здоровье.